# Link drive folder to gee: Display tiff images from drive to gee

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, mapping, geemap, google-drive

I have classified images using many different programs on gee and exported a series of classified images to a folder on my drive. I don't know how I can link that folder to gee so I can display the images onto the gee map.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any workflow to link a Drive folder to GEE. Despite saving images inside a Drive folder, I would store them within an ImageCollection asset and then load it into Python code using `ee.ImageCollection('assetid')`.

First, you need to create the image collection asset. I have not found a way to do it inside the Python API, so I have created the empty image collection in the GEE Code Editor under the Asset panel > New > Image Collection.

Then I create the images to export and load them inside the above empty Image Collection.:

```py
# Get images
to_export = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA').limit(3)
ids = to_export.aggregate_array('system:index').getInfo()

# Path to the empty image collection
col_path = 'users/test_user/test_col/'

for id in ids:

  name = id + '_exported'
  # Select the image to export
  img = to_export.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', id)).first()

  task = ee.batch.Export.image.toAsset(**{
    'image': img,
    'assetId': col_path + id,
    'description': 'insert_' + id,
    'dimensions': 5 # only to speed up the example
  })

  task.start()
```

Then you can access the image collection and use it with geemap like this:

```py
saved_col = ee.ImageCollection('users/test_user/test_col')
img = saved_col.first()
Map = geemap.Map()
Map.centerObject(img, zoom=5)
Map.addLayer(img)
Map.addLayerControl()
Map
```

I hope it helps you.